# unable to print the first column of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with two columns, however, I am unable to see the content of the first columns
I get this when I run the information.gain function on a data frame, to see which columns are statistically important to the response column

**Reproducible example**

Here, I have a data frame consisting of 4 columns, and I am trying to see it's effect on d. I get the output in weights.

```
install.packages('mlbench')
library(mlbench)
a = c(1,2,3,4,5)
b = c(4,2,45,6,2)
c = c('a','b','c','d','e')
d = c(10,20,30,40,50)
df = data.frame(a,b,c)
weights <- gain.ratio(d~., df)

> print(weights)
  attr_importance
a             NaN
b             NaN
c               1
> weights[,1]
[1] NaN NaN   1
> 
> weights[,2]
Error in `[.data.frame`(weights, , 2) : undefined columns selected
> 
> names(weights)
[1] "attr_importance"
>
```

As seen above, on printing 'weights', it prints the column names as the first column, so to say, and the second column is the weight. However, I am unable to print the first column

PS : The above is dummy data, a real output of computing gain.ratio might look like

```
                 attr_importance
X                    0.923133925
BMI                  0.000000000
hemoglobin           0.000000000
hematocrit           0.000000000
neutrophils          0.000000000
sodium               0.000000000
glucose              0.000000000
nitrogen             0.000000000
creatinine           0.000000000
```

Comment: Is `rownames(weights)` what you need?

Comment: Bryan has the right answer - you're after the rownames here. See `dim(weights)`, there is only one column

Comment: @BryanHanson, thanks Bryan. I checked with names(df), but just got the one column.

Comment: By the way, the example is not reproducible, we don't have `gain.ratio` which I don't see in any package.  But I don't think that has much to do with the answer.

Comment: `str(weights)` is also handy.  I find `str` one of the most helpful functions out there.